# Using void parameters

Tags: java

There is something that I tried to fix over and over and I couldn't.

So the program asks a user for 3 numbers a then asks for the percentage they want to add then these numbers goes to a void method:

So its like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Number 1: ");
        X1 = s.nextLong();
        System.out.print("Number 2: ");
        W1 = s.nextLong();
        System.out.print("Number 3: ");
        Z1 = s.nextLong();

        System.out.print("Percentage 1: ");
        int a = s.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Percentage 2: ");
        int b = s.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Percentage 3: ");
        int c = s.nextInt();
        Number(a,b,c);

}

public static void Number(int a, int b, int c)
{

    X1 = (long) (X1*(a/100 + 1));
    W1 = (long) (W1*(b/100 + 1));
    Z1 = (long) (Z1*(c/100 + 1));

}
```

But if I try to type the results the numbers don't change.

Note: X1,W1 and Z1 are all used as static long

And thanks in advance.

Comment: `public static void Number(int a, int b, int c) {` - this is not Javascript.. Try Java

Comment: And how do you output the results?

Comment: How are X1, W1, and Z1 defined?

Comment: I didnt write the whole program this is part of it (without the defined variables and imports) and i got the answer thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dividing the integer parameters by the integer `100` using--you guessed it--integer arithmetic which results in `0` for any value less than `100`. Use `100.0` to force floating point precision.

```
X1 = (long) (X1*(a / 100.0 + 1.0));
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless a,b,c >= 100, the expression

```
a/100
```

will be 0. Hence

```
something * (a/100 +1)
```

is

```
something * 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide your number by 100.0 in the Number method.